# Shared mutability in Java 8 stream lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Shared mutability is said to be evil in Java8, I have a use case like below where I am modifying a shared list in a parallelStream(), Just wanted to know if that is ok as a exception to reap benefits of parallelStream() or should just use imperative style code and sacrifice parallelism.

Also, is there is any other approach we can use to encounter this situation?

```java
private List<CustomClass> perfromActionInStream(Map<Long, List<CustomClass>> longCustomMap) {
        List<CustomClass> synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        longCustomMap
                .entrySet()
                .parallelStream()
                .forEach(entry -> performActionInLambda(synchronizedList, entry));

}

private void performActionInLambda(List<CustomClass> synchronizedList,
                              Map.Entry<Long, List<CustomClass>> entry) {
        try {
            Map<Long, CustomClass> recordsFromDb = persistService
                    .findInDb(entry.getKey());
            //Based on some condition 
            if(recordsFromDb.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
                //Some if condition on value for the entry
                recordsFromDb.remove(entry.getKey())
            }
            //:::Shared mutation::::Add all remaining elements from recordsFromDb to synchronizedList
            synchronizedList.addAll(recordsFromDb.values());
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred in lambda for fetching records from database", e);
            throw e; //throwing to stop further execution
        }
}
```

Comment: methodList is never used. So what is the purpose of it?

Comment: Thanks, @RavindraRanwala for pointing out, I have edited code to reflect correct situation.

Comment: I find your example somewhat confusing since it isn't clear what you are trying to do.  Note that `methodList` is not visible to method `doInnerMethod`.  And since `methodList` is a local variable it is not shared and does not require synchronization.  You also have additional syntax errors.  Can you provide a [mcve] and sufficient description to explain and demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Thanks, @WJS for the suggestions, I really appreciate it and have updated the code for the question. This question is more about a conceptual concern around shared mutability in streams and lambdas. Please excuse if I am not able to express it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, instead of doing it as a parallel stream, it would be much better if you could fetch the db records for all the keys in the map (or, in chunks depending on the size of the map). That would make a database call once or fewer times making the performance of the code better. Mutating a synchronized list in lambda executing in parallel may not be a good option, I feel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, doing all things in chunks makes sense, Since querying at once may be heavy on memory.